# Are White Walkers Immortals?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Except being stabbed by Dragonglass/Valyrian Steel which can kill the White Walkers, in addition to other things they can be killed by that we might not know at the moment, are White Walkers in *Game of Thrones* immortals, i.e. if we don't kill them by something could they stay alive forever?

Comment: It will be very difficult to answer it now , as we simply don't know. White walkers are not shown die with age or other means but we don't know. Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence

Comment: Just as a nitpick, the word Immortal implies that they don't die.  We know that they can in fact die so technically the answer to your question is no, they are not immortal.  But this is obviously not what you meant.  There could be a whole debate on this topic since there are many cases where fictional beings are said to be immortal, meaning they can not die of old age, even though they can die from other means.  But in the classic sense of the word, immortal means undying.

Comment: I think @sanpaco is right. I mean if you have seen wolverine. He never dies. He regenerates cells on being injured or stabbed so he is immortal,he has not died when anybody tries to kill him. So people are after his power of regeneration, if they remove that from his body he would become mortal and can be killed. Where as white walkers once stabbed(with dragon glass or valerian steel) cannot regenerate or come back to "life"(or whatever zombie state they are in). So technical they are not immortals.

Comment: Well, it makes sense that they age or at least mature, otherwise there would be half an army of male-baby white walkers. I think there were kids but they were older and mostly female? Apart from that I don't think there are any clues

Comment: Wolverine ages. And will eventually die. He's not biologically immortal.

Comment: They themselves may not know. The Night King is 8-10 thousand years old and he is the oldest, maybe after afew million year or something, but we don't know because they haven't been alive that long. It may be worth noting though that they do grow up, other wise they would stay as babies. Some of the White Walkers seem quite old and the Night King never fights, except when he kills the Three Eyes Raven. It may just be because he is to important but it may also be that he's getting alittle old for it.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be answered based on currently available information,  either book, show, or interview.

White Walkers can be killed by the mentioned weapons, so they are not completely immortal. And nothing has been stated about biological immortality, if they can live forever if they are not injured or otherwise externally interfered with.

Comment: In your own words, "This can't be answered...."
Then why did you answer it? Let me guess, just for the sake of it!

Comment: @happycoder because "inconclusive" is an answer.

Comment: Hmm, I think by now it's been shown that in show at least Nigth's King was around there for thousands of years.

Answer (score 0):

Their abilities are a little vague but they are basically immortal, only able to be killed by dragon glass (or obsidian weapons) and possibly Valyrian steel, a metal from a now-destroyed foreign land that’s in fairly short supply.

Comment: What do you mean "possibly" Valyrian steel? Have you watched the most recent season? Regardless, please explain how you know this information. Show supporting primary evidence that says they're immortal.